# !package inputenc error unicode character ​(u+200a)

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, characters

im currently writing my bachelors thesis and while inserting some cites and adding something to my bib file the above mentioned error occured. i tried to "fix" it by removing all the steps prior to the occuring error but it still remains and i just cant find any solution.
since im a total newbie in latex, i would be grateful for any quick help!
i found something that should remove this error but it doesnt:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200}{„ “}
```

which i insert directly after

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

but that still doesnt solve it

thx in advance guys!

Comment: the error is about character U+200a (HAIR SPACE)  but you have defined character U+0200 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOUBLE GRAVE)

Comment: Are you sure you want a literal Hair space character in your sources? Rather than define the character it is probably better to delete it.

Comment: i have deleted everything i added and its still there.
how could i define the hair space? (and what is it anyway?)

Comment: it is a thin space character, add  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200A}{!!!FIX ME!!!}`  to your preamble and then see where that text appears and retype that part of the source without the thin space character

Comment: ok at least its compiling without errors again, but fix me doesnt appear anywhere

Comment: If the text doesn't appear delete the definition and pretend it never happened:-) (it may have been in an auxiliary file and an earlier edit removed it after sufficient latex runs to regenerate everything)

Comment: definetly saved my day (maybe my life) there! muchas gracias! now i know how to handle another error of this type if it occurs

Answer (score 2):

it is a thin space character, add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200A}{!!!FIX ME!!!}
```

to your preamble and then see where that text appears and retype that part of the source without the thin space character

The log file should also pinpoint the error, it will look something like

```
(./somefile
<other messages>
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Δ (U+0394)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.766 \item \textbf{Distance $Δ$}
                                   - how much did we move by?
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

which tells you that the character is on line 766 of `somefile.tex`

Comment: thx it helped solve the error, the thing is, that !!!FIX ME!!! doesnt appear anywhere

Comment: @Stammer91 and does the error re-appear if you delete the definition?

Comment: strangely it doesnt. i just dont understand latex

Comment: @Stammer91 if you provided a small test file, it would be easy to debug, if you don't,  it isn't, but you have that character somewhere in your sources so an alternative is to use grep or perl or python etc and just search for the character.

Comment: i would have if i had any idea of how latex works

Comment: You don't really need that (we have that, or at least hopefully we do: I  wrote the code that's generating that error message:-) But you have the example, all you need to do is delete any text that you can delete while still showing the error and then post the resulting smallest file that has the error, if you half the file size at each iteration it should only take a few iterations to get down to a 1-page example. @Stammer91

Comment: i understand what u mean. the thing is the error appeared at a place i havent done anything ever before in the whole process. i had that experience already once before that an error was marked at a position where there actually was none. thus i had no idea where exactly my error happend

Comment: @Stammer91 the log file with the error message will show the file and line number where the character is, so it should be pretty easy to find really?

Comment: thats the thing: it didnt! no line, no file

Comment: @Stammer91 are you sure? what does the log file look like starting at the nearest encosing `(` to the `?` that follows the error?

Comment: @Stammer91 I put a log file fragment into my answer...

Comment: 100% sure! my eyes are not the best but i could see that. i cant tell u the exact error message, since it doesnt appear anymore

Comment: @Stammer91 tex error messages _always_ have a line number, unless they are reading text from the terminal , when the line number is shown as `<*>`  But anyway let's just drop it: you have  the document working:-)

Comment: maybe i dont understand what u mean at all, but thats on me. im really grateful that u solved it!