# Unknown Unicode character 128 = U+0080

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, unicode, input-encodings

I am working on my PhD thesis and have a huge file to compile. In the package file, I included the following package and commented chapter by chapter but still, I get this error. I'll appreciate if you can help me to solve this issue. 
I am compiling by pdflatex and using the BibTeX for the bibliography.

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

P.s. error is about this character (â) but I do not have this character in my file.

> ```
> Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 128 = U+0080,
> (ucs)                possibly declared in uni-0.def.
> (ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.
> ```

Comment: Since `biblatex` (note the `la`, not BibTeX) is incompatible with `utfx`/`ucs` it is unlikely that you are using it, so I removed the tag and replaced it with the  more generic `bibliographies` tag. `U+0080` is not a printable Unicode char, it seems something went wrong in your encoding. Is your `.bib` file maybe encoded in Latin-1? (Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15271453) Make sure that all files involved have the same encoding (ideally UTF-8). Usually it is enough to use `utf8` instead of `utf8x` nowadays, so I'd use only `utf8` if possible.

Comment: I would use the standard utf8 option rather than utf8x (actually inputenc isn't needed at all with recent releases)  but character 128 is an undefined control character in Unicode, it is not â which is U+00E2 make sure your file is saved in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @moewe,  I changed it to utf8 but still, I get the error. Same error even points to a line that is commented.

Comment: If the encoding of one of your files is wrong, a change from `utf8x` to `utf8` was unlikely to resolve the issue, but it was a good idea nonetheless. Double-check the reported line in the raw `.log` file. In case several different files are involved it may well be that a line number does not refer to the main `.tex` file, but to a different included or auxiliary file. You can find out which file the message refers to by tracking parentheses in the `.log`, see David's answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481423/35864.

Comment: @moewe I went through the .log file and trace all the chapters but no error printed in the log file.

Comment: Mhhh, if something reports `Package ucs Error` there must be something in the `.log` about that. Delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, ...) and try again

Comment: @moewe found it. It is in the bbl file. [author={Palau, Adri{\`a} Salvador and Liang, Zhenglin and L{\"u}tgehetmann, Daniel and Parlikad, Ajith Kumar},]

Comment: Mhhh, `Adri{`a}` looks wrong, but I wouldn't have expected an error along those lines. But if it works now ...

Comment: @moewe no it did not work, Adri{\`a} it's like this, still got the same error and in a different line.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you said you had found the error?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and just solved it. Couldn't display the weird "pad" character in Atom or anything so I couldn't delete it easily. However, I deleted and manually retyped the section of the paragraph that it was in. Then, my TeX file compiled with no errors. So not a bug, there literally was a U+0080 somewhere in the file.

More detail: I have no idea how this "pad" character U+0080 was inserted. For some reason one of my two dozen TeX source files (chapters, front matter, and back matter are all separate files) was throwing this error that it couldn't parse U+0080. I opened the offending file and it said it was in ISOLatin9, instead of UTF-8 as expected. I resaved as UTF-8. Still gave the error when recompiling. I deleted and retyped the sentence that supposedly had the character and it compiled successfully. So it did literally have the U+0080 character in there, but I have no idea how one of a dozen TeX files ends up with this problem.

Comment: Please check if your file maybe used to contain a euro sign "€" which is missing now. If your file actually was Windows-1252 encoded and you converted it from Latin9 to UTF-8, all euro signs would be converted to U+0080.

Comment: This was almost certainly it.