# Unknown Unicode character 128 = U+0080, U+0098, U+0099

Tags: unicode, compilation-error

I have the same problem which is described here:
[Unknown Unicode character 128 = U+0080](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481648/300496).

Error because of `U+0080`, `U+0098` and `U+0099`.

The errors are displayed in my masterdoc in the line directly underneath `\printbibliography`. Can I assume, because of this, that the character must be somewhere within my bibliography?

If so: any tips on how to find/display them there? Manually deleting and rewriting as AmiDel did, does not seem to be an option here.

**Edit**: I tried

> \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+0080}{!!!FIX ME!!!}

causes error:

> Cannot define non-active Unicode char value < 0080.

Comment: Make a copy of your project. Replace the body of the your document with `\nocite{*} \printbibliography` and then keep deleting half of the bib file to narrow down where the problem comes from. (best delete all the auxiliary files between compilations)

Comment: thanks
finally got biber running again, which pointed out another error with an incorrect date format in one of my sources. I corrected that, now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When trying to debug this with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` you need to omit the `U+`, so just `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0080}{!!!FIX ME!!!}`.

Comment: "The errors are displayed in my masterdoc in the line directly underneath \printbibliography. Can I assume, because of this, that the character must be somewhere within my bibliography?"  No, if the error is in the bibliography the error would be reported with the line number in the generated `.bbl` file that has the control character

Comment: The bizarre unicode characters are often in references from some databases, but when they are in the main text the result is the same, so the easy way to debug is    make a  "hello world" document, place the insidious character between these two words and test the solution.  Once it works, you only have to do the same in your long document with references that compile as if it was in  the event horizon of a black hole.

Comment: update (from a few weeks ago, sorry for the delay):
I didn't find the unicode characters within my text, but after correcting some info in zotero (titles with unexpected characters, and/or dates in a wrong format), which zotero automatically took over from some websites, and integrated into the bib file, and rerunning, biber it seemed to work. Not exactly sure if that's really the initial problem, but it's good enough for me for now.
thanks for your help :)