# LaTeX Error: Unicode character е (U+0435)

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I copy-pasted a paragraph from my google doc onto overleaf and I'm getting this error. I don't understand what it means and I realise that it has to do something with latex not expecting a character but I can't pinpoint which one. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

U+0435  is CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE

In general not all of Unicode can be pre-defined and you may get this error and have to add a definition as shown here

[!package inputenc error unicode character ​(u+200a)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481423/package-inputenc-error-unicode-character-u200a/481427#481427)

But U+0435 is in the base Cyrillic range that *should* be defined automatically once you use a Cyrillic font encoding.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

еееееее

\end{document}
```